# Codeigniter. Autoload models, will things get slower?

Tags: codeigniter

I am building an API using Codeigniter.
In this API I got 10 models that I use now and then.

Currently I am loading them when I need them but I am thinking of auto loading
all models instead (to cut down on space in my controllers).

What will I loose by doing this? Will they cause things to slow down?

Answer (score 2):

You are instructing CI to auto load your models into memory, which will increase memory footprint. I think autoloading won't have much effect of performance if you have plenty of RAM available but if you run PHP using `mod_php` then it might cause some slowdown because php processes have to respawned per request.

In any case, before making a decision -- **Profile your app**! there are two ways to do it.

1. [PECL APD](http://www.php.net/apd)
2. [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) + kcachegrind (linux) or wincachegrind (windows) and it'll show you a few pretty charts that detail the exact timings, counts and memory usage (but you need another extension for that).

I would suggest `PECL APD` extension because its easier to setup

Comment: Actually, CodeIgniter already has a [profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html). I don't know if it's enough for your needs.

Comment: So autoloading is fine as long as I got enough RAM? I got 1GB is that ok?

Comment: Do not autoload them, as you are only using each one sporadically. Just let codeigniter take care of the memory usage as an on demand issue. No need having 10 models in memory when you are only using 1 or 2

Comment: @Jonathan: 1GB is plenty of RAM but I strongly suggest to profile your app. for basic use, even the inbuilt profiler of CI should be enough. Turn it on; test with autoloading vs without autoloading.  you will have your answer :)

Comment: Problem is that I do not use views. I am building an API.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to built a API client & do loading testing using that