# Autoloading all models in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Are there any disadvantages to just putting all models in `$autoload['model']` instead of loading them only as necessary?

Comment: yes, you load stuff that in some places on your website is absolutely not necessary. It's not clean. How less you have to include how better & faster your website will be.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [CodeIgniter Profiler Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) to see how your application performs auto-loading all models versus loading them only when needed.  I'd recommend looking at execution time and memory usage.

Here is a similar question with some more suggestions for profiling your application.  [Codeigniter. Autoload models, will things get slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081482/codeigniter-autoload-models-will-things-get-slower)